# Swipestripe Paypal Module not working for me

Tags: paypal, silverstripe, swipestripe

I am using Swipestripe to build an ecommerce website. I have implemented the *frank-mullenger/payment-paypal* module for the checkout process. However i am having trouble with this; it is all installed correctly as per the instructions however when i click "Proceed to Pay" it is not redirecting to Paypal to get payment. The payment is failing and sending me to the AccountOrder page

Does anyone know what could cause this or a fix?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: Yea the issue was that it wouldn't work on a local wampserver. Once the website was added to live hosting with my provider it worked flawlessly